# How to change the font according to the width of CATextLayer ?

Tags: ios, layer, catextlayer

For UILabel we have adjustFontSizetoWidth property is there like that we have anything for CATextLayer.

I want to adjust the string to be fit in given textlayer width.

Answer (score 0):

Set `wrapped` property to `YES`. By default it is set to `NO`.

Comment: Thanks. But i am not asking for multiple lines. I need single line adjusted to be in given width.  According to the width font should be decrease.